# Passing Value between forms vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i'm using tow forms, and when i retrieve a value of text box from form 1 to form 2, and make calculation in form 2. I try to send the calculation to form 1. the problem is the first value in form 1 is missing when i load the form 1:in the form 1
`

```
public class Form3
Public Property StringPass As String
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


Dim obje As New Form2  
chargemetr.Text = Convert.ToString("somme  calulations using StringPass  ")
      obje.ChargeM = chargemetr.Text'
      obje.Show()
```

`
in the form 2

`

```
Public Class Form2
Public Property ChargeM As String 
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
{.
.
.
some code
ChargeMetrique.Text = ChargeM}

  Private Sub ChargeMetrique_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChargeMetrique.Click

    Dim obj As New Form3
    obj.StringPass = Diametre.Text
    obj.Show()

    'ChargeMetrique.Text = obj.chargemetr.Text

End Sub

`
```

Comment: Just about every entry under **Related** applies.

Comment: please reread the code that i post !

Comment: Please reread the links under **Related**.  You are creating a ***new*** form1 in that click event so it is not the same form as before.  Thats what `New` does.  You need a reference to the *original* form

Comment: Thank's a lot, you have save me.